# generate DOB in robotframework using FakerLibrary

Tags: python, robotframework, faker

My goal is writing test cases for webservice which have also validations on user's age input (eligibility for service). I have a request XML where i fill the date of birth as follows;

```
${updatedXml}=  Set Element Text    ${root}    ${randomDob}               xpath=.//birthdate
```

Now, to fill the date of birth (randomDob) i'm using the Get Current Date function, with an increment:

```
${birthdate}=   Get Current Date    result_format=%Y-%m-%d    increment=-6391day
```

However this does't make it 'real' random. I would rather use FakerLibrary.date_of_birth in this way:

```
${randomDob}=    FakerLibrary.date_of_birth     minimum_age=14  maximum_age=17
```

Now the output of this function for fakerlibrary seems python datetime.date (verified via evaluate), but i somehow cannot use it to fill the variable in my xml element:

> **TypeError: cannot serialize datetime.date(2004, 3, 27) (type date)**.

When i log it to the console i get:

> 2004-03-27

How do i convert the output to normal string, so i can fill the XML element with it?
I have tried 'Convert to string', but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Convert Date` to transform it in a string with your desired format:

```
${randomDob}=    Convert Date    ${randomDob}    result_format=%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: Hi Todor, now i get:  ValueError: Unsupported input '1959-01-19'.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError: Unsupported input '1959-01-19' you get is because the data object you are passing to Convert Date is not one of the [supported formats](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#library-documentation-top).

The solution I used was to add time just after the variable:

```
${randomDob}=    Convert Date    ${randomDob} 00:00:00    result_format=%Y-%m-%d
```